# SSL certificate with multiple SANs and wildcard custom domain

Tags: azure-api-management

Is it possible to use a single SSL certificate containing multiple subject alternative names with a wildcard custom domain name in Azure API Management?  Upgrading to the premium tier of Azure API Management which supports multiple host names for the Proxy endpoint isn't an option and I'm hoping to avoid managing two separate instances of API Management if possible.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Multiple custom hostname is a premium feature hence only Premium tier is the only solution.</strike>

Single SSL certificate containing with a wildcard custom domain name is allowed in all tiers of api management.